# What is the difference between Manufacturing/Design process of CMOS IC for Automotive Grade 1 and Grade 2

Tags: automotive

I see various CMOS IC in the same datasheet has Automotive Grade 1 [125 deg.C] and Grade 2 [105 deg. C] part numbers.
Can you explain what are the possible manufacturing or design differences between those two grades?
Assume for example
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC9S08MP16DS.pdf
Look at Section 3.1 for the part number in the datasheet.
You will see 3 temperature ranges.
Question is what is the manufacturing or design differences for the part.
I need some idea about the possible differences either from design perspective or from manufacturing perspective.
Thank you.
Regards

Also another datasheet with multiple temperature range
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC9S08EL32.pdf
Appendix B shows the order info

Comment: It may be it isnt necessarily design.  I could also be screen, parts that pass screen at the higher temps ad frequencies go in one bucket, others parts go in the lower buckets.  Yes it could be part of the process or it could also be part of the design, unlikely though, those would have their own part number and be one grade or the other not described as both...

Comment: It could be different materials. Such as ceramic packaging vs plastic.

Answer (score 1):

Having decades of wide-temperature PCB and silicon design experience, I'll provide some opinions.

Usually I'll run simulations at 125C or 150C (if the semiconductor foundary models can be trusted to 150C), just to ensure there is functional and waveform margins; should a waveform turn *ugly* at 150C (e.g. not full swing, or imbalanced slewing, or overshoot rears its head) I'll examine the circuit and look to cure the *ugliness*. In this manner, I avoid warrantee failures out in the field. The customers stay happy and trusting the ICs.